# Is it true that Tagged initialization allows the reordering of structure members?

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, c99

I am currently reading "Linux Device Driver" third ed.

Extract:

> The scull device driver implements only the most important device
>   methods. Its file_operations structure is initialized as follows:
>
> ```
> struct file_operations scull_fops = {
>     .owner = THIS_MODULE,
>     .llseek = scull_llseek,
>     .read = scull_read,
>     .write = scull_write,
>     .ioctl = scull_ioctl,
>     .open = scull_open,
>     .release = scull_release,
>  };
> ```
>
> This
>   declaration uses the standard C tagged structure initialization
>   syntax. This syntax is preferred because it makes drivers more
>   portable across changes in the definitions of the structures and,
>   arguably, makes the code more compact and readable. **Tagged
>   initialization allows the reordering of structure members;** in some
>   cases, substantial **performance improvements** have been realized by
>   placing pointers to frequently accessed members in the same hardware
>   cache line.

I may read it mistakenly. Does they mean that the final layout in memory of the object will differ from the initial structure definition? Thus being unportable? I fail to see a viable implementation of what is suggested. Can someone explain me what is suggested in the last paragraph? Does they suggest alternatively that the final placement of the functions in memory will be affected and get closer to each other? Thus being more likely in the same cache line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final layout in memory of the object is *fully dependent from `struct file_operations` definition* in `linux/fs.h` header file.

They mean that this definition can change **order** for performance reason, and that change will not break any driver, which use *tagged* initialization of its members (as opposite to unnamed initialization of members *in order* they appear in the structure's definition).

Moreover, aside from reordering structure members, it is possible to **add** new members and **remove** unused ones without breaking existed drivers. And this actually happens in the kernel.

Comment: Ok. So, for you, what the book suggest is that the struct definition may be changed later for optmizing performance. What the book highligh is the fact that it won't break the code for drivers which uses tagged initialisation. Indeed youre explanation is obviously the correct one. Reading this my question looks stupid now. Anyway. Thank you. By the way: removing fields may break drivers code, when they reference the removed field from a tagged intialisation, right?

Comment: `removing fields may break drivers code, when they reference the removed field from a tagged intialisation, right?` - Yes, it may break.